# Get the whole word if a few characters present in Text File Content

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have text file which contains more than 100 paragraph. I want to find & list the words that contain a specific string.

This is my text file content:

> A computer is a general purpose device that can be programmed to carry
>   out a set of arithmetic or logical operations automatically. Since a
>   sequence of operations can be readily changed, the computer can solve
>   more than one kind of problem.

I want to retrieve the words that contains `ra`. And it should return
`general`, `programmed` & `operations`.

Here is my code:

```
with open('computer.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if "ra" in line:
            line_split = line.split(' ')
            for each in line_split:
                if "ra" in each:
                    print each
```

What would be the most efficient method to do this ?

Comment: Use python regex module (re) : https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re

Comment: What exactly do you consider a word?  Any sequence of non-space characters? Any sequence of letters? Are non-ASCII letters allowed? Is punctuation within a word allowed? etc.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression would work nicely here:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r"\b\w*ra\w*\b")
>>> r.findall("A computer is a general purpose device that can be programmed to carry out a set of arithmetic or logical operations automatically. Since a sequence of operations can be readily changed, the computer can solve more than one kind of problem.")
['general', 'programmed', 'operations', 'operations']
```

This list contains duplicates which can be removed via a simple `set()` call (which in turn removes the order of the elements, so if you need to preserve that, a bit more work is necessary).

Note that the regex is rather naive in what it considers a "word":

```
\b   # Start of an alphanumeric word
\w*  # Match any number of word characters [A-Za-z0-9_]
ra   # Match ra
\w*  # Match any number of word characters
\b   # End of a word
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be reduced to:

```
with open('computer.txt', 'r') as f:
  print [word for word in f.read().split() if "ra" in word]
  ['general', 'programmed', 'operations', 'operations']
```

Timings on a file with 100 paragraphs:

```
In [7]: %%timeit
with open('computer.txt', 'r') as f:
    r = re.compile(r"\b\w*ra\w*\b")
    r.findall(f.read())
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.82 ms per loop

In [8]: %%timeit
with open('computer.txt', 'r') as f:
      [word for word in f.read().split() if "ra" in word]
   ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 ms per loop
```

Or use string.translate to differentiate between  `operations` and `operations.` etc..:

```
In [18]: %%timeit
with open('out.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [word.translate(None,  string.punctuation) for word in f.read().split() if "ra" in word]
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.13 ms per loop

In [19]: %%timeit
with open('out.txt', 'r') as f:
    r = re.compile(r"\b\w*ra\w*\b")    r.findall(f.read())
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.53 ms per loop
```

Comment: I guess the best method will be determined by the exact definition of "word" which OP hasn't yet provided. If a simple split on whitespace is sufficient (and for example `operation` and `operation.` should be considered distinct matches), then regexes are not needed.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, Yes but I was just going by the OP's original code.